When does a Nondeterministic Turing Machine halt?
I've seen several definitions and discussions on this topic, but I cannot find the exact definitions of "Nondeterministic Turing Machine (NTM) that halts on an input x" and "NTM that loops on an input x".

I understand that according to many definitions "an NTM accepts a string x if at least one of the branches in its computation (tree) halts in an accepting state". Does this imply that the NTM halts (in addition to accepting), even when there are computation branches on which it loops?

Is it correct to separate the defintions of "NTM that accepts an input x" and "NTM that halts on an input x"?

Would it be correct to say that an NTM loops (does not halt) only if there is at least one branch in its computation tree on which it loops and all the other branches are either "looping" or "rejecting" branches. The reason is that only in this case (i.e., when there is no accepting branch) we are not able to say if the NTM accepts, rejects or loops.



Please ask only one question per post.  What textbooks have you consulted?

It may help to consider that an NTM is equivalent to a deterministic TM.
A Turing machine can halt either by accepting or rejecting an input.
An NTM can halt by meeting one of two conditions:

Accepting an input on any one of its branches.
Rejecting on all of its branches.

So, to answer your questions:

Yes. If an NTM accepts on one branch, it will halt.
Yes, as an NTM may halt by rejecting an input on all of its branches.
Yes, as it will not have met the two conditions listed above.


As far as I know, "halts" is not defined for a NTM.  You can talk about whether a particular computation path halts.  You can talk about whether a NTM halts on all possible computation paths.
In contrast, the notion of "accepts" the input is well-defined and standard.
